# calling a function from a stored procedure in oracle

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

Usually we use `Select function(param) from dual` to retrieve a value from function. I am trying to get a value from a function in a stored procedure in oracle. But it's getting Syntax error. The code is like this

> voucher_no := select Func_Voucher_No_Gen (vc_comp_code,vou_dt,'JN') from dual;

Can anyone suggest what's wrong ? thanks in advance.

Comment: You don't need a query to call a function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Direct assignment,

`voucher_no := Func_Voucher_No_Gen (vc_comp_code,vou_dt,'JN') ;`

should do the job.

Or,

`select Func_Voucher_No_Gen (vc_comp_code,vou_dt,'JN') into voucher_no  from dual;`